# Java; I initialize an array in a constructor but it only gives me back zero values, why?

Tags: java, arrays, class, initialization

I initialize an array in a constructor but it only gives me back zero values, why?
I am writing this in processing 2 thought, but I don't think it has anything to do with the problem.

Also, what is the syntax to initialize this outside the constructor? (when the object is created)
Sorry if am unclear about my problem.

```
class ArrayInClass {
    String test;
    private int[] data = new int[3];

    // ---
    ArrayInClass(String TempTest) {
        test = TempTest;
    }

    // ---
    public ArrayInClass() {
        data = new int[] { 10, 20, 25 };
    }

}

ArrayInClass InsTArrayInClass = new ArrayInClass ("TEST" );
println( InsTArrayInClass.test);
println( InsTArrayInClass.data[0] + "  "  + InsTArrayInClass.data[1]);
```

Comment: ` new ArrayInClass ("TEST" );` call the `ArrayInClass (String TempTest)`constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the default constructor, in which you initialize the array. You are calling a constructor that only initializes `test`.

Either change :

```
InsTArrayInClass = new ArrayInClass ("TEST" );
```

to :

```
InsTArrayInClass = new ArrayInClass ();
```

or call your default constructor from the other constructor :

```
ArrayInClass (String TempTest)
{
    this();
    test = TempTest;
}
```

Comment: OP's class has no default constructor. even thought that one looks like a `default one`

Comment: @Kent What do you call the parameter-less constructor then? Do you call it default only when it's generated by the compiler?

Comment: default constructor init the fields with their default value. like object=null, int=0 etc. nothing else. as same as `public SomeClass(){}`.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the array in the nullary constructor, which is not the one you call in your test code. You can fix it by delegating to the nullary constructor:

```
ArrayInClass (String TempTest)
{this(); test = TempTest;}
```

Note that your initializer of `data` is redundant in that case:

```
private int[] data = new int[3];
```

the array you create above will be immediatly replaced by the array created and initialized in the nullary constructor. You are free to remove that initializer:

```
private int[] data;
```

As a final note, you'll also have to invest some time in learning about and applying Java coding standards.